# How can i get my reactive form can't display

Tags: html, node.js, angular

I am using Angular 9 and I designed a form. It displayed the very first time when I didn't add some more codes to handle errors in each input field but immediately I added some those codes, all I get is a blank page when I run it.

It, first of all, gave me an error saying: Can't bind 'formGroup' because it is not a known element of form. I added FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule to both my app.module.ts and app.component.ts files respectively. That cleared the error BUT my form still won't display.

My code is below:

```
<!-- Material form subscription -->
<mdb-card>
  <mdb-card-header class="info-color white-text text-center py-4">
    <h1>
      <strong>Welcome</strong>
    </h1>
  </mdb-card-header>

  <!--Card content-->
  <mdb-card-body class="px-lg-5">
    <!-- Form -->
    <form [formGroup]="registerForm"
      class="text-center"
      style="color: #757575;"
      (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
    >
      <h3>
        BBrainz is an app <br />
        <br />
        Please enter your information below.
      </h3>

      <!-- School name -->
      <div class="md-form form-group mt-3">
        <input
          mdbInput
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          formControlName="schoolName"
          id="schoolName"
          placeholder="School name"
        />
        <label for="schoolName">School Name</label>
        <mdb-error
          *ngIf="schoolName.invalid && (schoolName.dirty || schoolName.touched)"
          >Input invalid</mdb-error
        >
        <mdb-success
          *ngIf="schoolName.valid && (schoolName.dirty || schoolName.touched)"
          >Input valid</mdb-success
        >
      </div>

      <!-- School Address -->
      <div class="md-form form-group mt-3">
        <input
          mdbInput
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          formControlName="schoolAddress"
          id="schoolAddress"
          placeholder="School address"
        />
        <label for="schoolAddress">School Address</label>
        <mdb-error
          *ngIf="
            schoolAddress.invalid &&
            (schoolAddress.dirty || schoolAddress.touched)
          "
          >Input invalid</mdb-error
        >
        <mdb-success
          *ngIf="
            schoolAddress.valid &&
            (schoolAddress.dirty || schoolAddress.touched)
          "
          >Input valid</mdb-success
        >
      </div>

      <!-- Grid row -->
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Grid column for city -->
        <div class="col">
          <!-- Material input -->
          <div class="md-form mt-0">
            <input
              mdbInput
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              formControlName="city"
              placeholder="City"
              id="city"
            />
            <label for="city">City</label>
            <mdb-error *ngIf="city.invalid && (city.dirty || city.touched)"
              >Input invalid</mdb-error
            >
            <mdb-success *ngIf="city.valid && (city.dirty || city.touched)"
              >Input valid</mdb-success
            >
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of grid column for city -->

        <!-- Grid column for state-->
        <div class="col">
          <!-- Material input -->
          <div class="md-form mt-0">
            <input
              mdbInput
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              formControlName="state"
              placeholder="State"
            />
            <label for="state">State</label>
            <mdb-error *ngIf="state.invalid && (state.dirty || state.touched)"
              >Input invalid</mdb-error
            >
            <mdb-success *ngIf="state.valid && (state.dirty || state.touched)"
              >Input valid</mdb-success
            >
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of grid column for state -->

        <!-- Grid column for zip code-->
        <div class="col">
          <!-- Material input -->
          <div class="md-form mt-0">
            <input
              mdbInput
              type="number"
              class="form-control"
              formControlName="zipCode"
              placeholder="Zip code"
            />
            <label for="zipCode">Zip Code</label>
            <mdb-error
              *ngIf="zipCode.invalid && (zipCode.dirty || zipCode.touched)"
              >Input invalid</mdb-error
            >
            <mdb-success
              *ngIf="zipCode.valid && (zipCode.dirty || zipCode.touched)"
              >Input valid</mdb-success
            >
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of grid column for zip code -->
      </div>
      <!-- Grid row -->

      <!-- School registeration number -->
      <div class="md-form form-group mt-3">
        <input
          mdbInput
          type="number"
          class="form-control"
          formControlName="schRegNumber"
          id="schRegNumber"
          placeholder="School reg number"
        />
        <label for="schRegNumber">School Registeration Number</label>
        <mdb-error
          *ngIf="
            schRegNumber.invalid && (schRegNumber.dirty || schRegNumber.touched)
          "
          >Input invalid</mdb-error
        >
        <mdb-success
          *ngIf="
            schRegNumber.valid && (schRegNumber.dirty || schRegNumber.touched)
          "
          >Input valid</mdb-success
        >
        <small
          id="materialRegisterFormPhoneHelpBlock"
          class="form-text text-muted mb-4"
        >
          The school must be registered.
        </small>
      </div>

      <!-- School Email -->
      <div class="md-form form-group mt-3">
        <input
          mdbInput
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          formControlName="schoolEmail"
          id="schoolEmail"
          placeholder="Email"
        />
        <label for="email">School Email</label>

        <small
          id="materialRegisterFormPhoneHelpBlock"
          class="form-text text-muted mb-4"
        >
          It must be a valid email.
        </small>
      </div>

      <!-- School phone number -->
      <div class="md-form form-group mt-3">
        <input
          mdbInput
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          formControlName="schoolPhoneNumber"
          id="schoolPhoneNumber"
          placeholder="Phone number"
        />
        <label for="phoneNumber">School Phone Number</label>
        <small
          id="materialRegisterFormPhoneHelpBlock"
          class="form-text text-muted mb-4"
        >
          It must be a valid phone number.
        </small>
      </div>

      <!-- Register button -->
      <button
        mdbBtn
        color="info"
        outline="true"
        rounded="true"
        block="true"
        class="my-4 waves-effect z-depth-0"
        mdbWavesEffect
        type="submit"
        [disabled]="disabledSubmitButton"
      >
        Register
      </button>

      <hr />

      <!-- Terms of service -->
      <p>
        By clicking <em>Register</em> you agree to our
        <a href="" target="_blank">terms of service</a>.
      </p>
    </form>
    <!-- Form -->
  </mdb-card-body>
</mdb-card>
<!-- Material form registeration -->
```

Can someone tell me why I can't see my form and also tell me where to correct so that I can see it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `<form *ngIf="registerForm" [formGroup]="registerForm"..>` for avoid initial errors, and `<pre>{{form.value|json}}</pre>` in the .html to see if you really has created the form. Check if there are errors in console

Comment: I added the <form *ngIf="registerForm .....> but it is still blank.. the code i uploaded is my .html file.

Comment: in any place you need put some like this.registerForm=new FormGroup({schoolName:new FormControl()...}) or using FormBuilder. if you has no variabele "registerForm" or has no value, your app can not show nothing

Comment: this error normally appears when you are trying to access the formGroup before it is initialized, it looks like the issue is on your controller (component) side, could you add its code too?

Comment: did you check the console for errors?

Comment: Sorry for the late delay. i had to visit my doctor for some medical attention. my code is below:

Comment: Sorry guys. I had to go see my doctor for medical reasons. I removed the <mdb-error></mdb-error> and <mdb-success></mdb-success> tags and my form displayed. i copied and pasted other examples which had the same tags and theirs displayed with no issues. i don't know why mine didn't.